# How to wrap a Go dependency with custom behavior?

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a wrapper around a 2nd-level indirect dependency, i.e. to go from here:

```
myApp -> libA -> libB
```

to here:

```
myApp -> libA -> myWrapper -> libB
```

where my code is strictly limited to *myApp* and *myWrapper*, and the libraries are third-party code that is out of my reach to change.

For the sake of an example, let's say I would just want the wrapper to do a `fmt.Print()` every time *libA* makes a call to *libB*. Using a [replace directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in *myApp*'s `go.mod` does work, and the wrapper prints messages when *libA* calls functions from *libB*:

```golang
replace third.party/libB => ../myWrapper
```

However, the problem comes when having the wrapper call the *actual* function from *libB*. Turns out that **the wrapper cannot import *libB***, because it causes an import cycle:

```
$ go build .
package example.com/myApp
        imports third.party/libA
        imports third.party/libB    (-- this is actually my wrapper)
        imports third.party/libB: import cycle not allowed
```

After getting **so close**, it seems I'm only missing a small piece of the puzzle to achieve my purpose. But so far it was impossible to "force" the replacement of *libB* while at the same time allowing the wrapper to import the actual *libB* instead of importing itself due to the `replace` directive.

Are there any solutions to this, or alternative ways to achieve the same?

---

Extra info:

The reason for this is that *libB* is a data engine used by *libA*, and I want to implement support for a different engine, while *libA* should not even notice about it (also its maintainers won't be interested in this change, it's just a need I have myself).

I've seen [How to wrap a Go package with only a few modifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67311994/how-to-wrap-a-go-package-with-only-a-few-modifications) but I would be interested in wrapping a whole module and having my wrapper to implement the whole public API of the wrapped dependency.

Comment: You cannot do exactly what you want. You will have to fork libA .